# IIS serving an old version of files

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching, iis-7, web-deployment

I am developing an ASP.NET application and deploying to an IIS 7 server via WebDeploy. This is a single server (no web farm or anything like this). I've been using the same setup for two years with no problems. Since last night, the server seems to be "stuck" on the last version of the web that I deployed before dinner. I deployed a couple of new versions today, but the server keeps serving the old pages.

I have triple checked this. When I log into the server via RDP and I open a specific ASPX file, I can see that it's the new version I've just deployed, so the server is actually storing the new versions. However, when I visit the web site over HTTP from my computer, I get the old version of the file.

I have restarted the server (the whole machine, not just IIS). I have disabled the IIS cache. I have disabled the compression cache. I have tried from multiple client computers, including one from which I had never ever visited this site (so no client cache may exist). But nothing worked.

I am aware that similar issues have been reported, and I have read some posts about it. But I seem to have exhausted all possible checks. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Did you set output caching rule for yoru website? When you face this issue, you could enable failed request tracing. It always display the response body and would also probably show the root cause.

Comment: @JokiesDing: Caching was disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggling, I managed to solve this issue. I deleted the whole web site from the server, and I deployed it from a computer other than my usual development machine. This fixed the issue.

However, I am still baffled at why this happened. It must have been a glitch with WebDeploy and/or IIS.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on IIS 10.0.17763.1, and I have to say this answer doesn't actually solve the issue. On mine, I have copied the application files to a new location on the same server and created a new application pool, and it works with the new file. The new location with the OLD app pool also works. Even the old files with the NEW app pool works. But the old pool with the existing file location doesn't.